# Drag an imageview item on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I need to drag on ImageView to a UITableView. I have implemented the dragging but now I need to determine the cell on which the image view is dragged and dropped.

I can get the visible cells but than calculating the exact indexpath doesn't seem clear.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the point *in the table view* from your dragging callback and then check

```
indexPathForRowAtPoint:
```